# Mysql SUM and group by no working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have just started a new question to make this a bit more clear.

I have just migrated from MS SQL to MySQL this query worked in MS SQL

This is rstCombinedChartData

[image]

Then the result which should have 2 column 'yes' and 'no' with values for some reason on mysql I'm getting just one and itemcolumn false.

[image]

As you can see for some reason it's adding up all the results giving 551 where it should be like this:

```
Yes x 
No x
```

Why?

This is the SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    itemColumn
    ,SUM(valueColumn) AS valueColumn
    ,label
    FROM
    rstCombinedChartData
        GROUP BY
        label
        ,itemColumn
        ORDER BY
         label DESC
    ,itemColumn DESC
```

Comment: Your query that shows the data is a `union`.  My guess is all the values from `rstCombinedChartData` only have the label `false`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried removing label as suggest but I get the same result! i.e. I tried: SELECT itemColumn ,SUM(valueColumn) AS valueColumn
            FROM rstCombinedChartData
            GROUP BY itemColumn
            ORDER BY itemColumn DESC

Comment: In the 2nd query, the entire table  "rstChartData" is missing.  What happened to the union all?  I think you're saying rstcombinedchartdata is defined as that union all query... but that doesn't make sense to define it on itself.  You should start by just doing queries on the tables without group by to see what's in there.  Try using distinct, etc.  Count the rows - maybe the data didn't even come over in the migration?  Also try not using the rstcombinedchartdata - if that is in fact just a view.

Answer (score 1):

Plase try:

```
SELECT itemColumn, SUM(CAST(valueColumn AS SIGNED)), label FROM rstCombinedChartData GROUP BY label, itemColumn ORDER BY label DESC, itemColumn DESC
```

Comment: give error: "SELECT" at line 4, column 5. Was expecting one of: "AVG" ... "COUNT" ... "MAX" ... "MIN" ... "NOT" ... "NULL" ... "PRIOR" ... "SUM"

Comment: gave me the same result sorry